# Interface and duck typing in dynamic languages

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface

e.g. in dynamic language such as PHP, since we have duck typing, is Interface only a constraint, it has no use in practice?

Comment: It does have a use if you follow Design By Contract (which I do).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any point for interfaces in dynamic languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91618/is-there-any-point-for-interfaces-in-dynamic-languages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two cases I can think of which give it some practical importance:

1. If desired, an interface allows you to behave like a faux static typed language: you can check the runtime type of an object to see if it implements the interface, and you can also get PHP to do it for you automatically with [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).
2. It documents the relationships between type hierarchies (in a big library). This is a big practical gain for a human trying to understand said hierarchies.